# How to cross reference across child documents in Classicthesis LyX version

Tags: cross-referencing, lyx, classicthesis

I have perfect solution for cross referencing propositions etc within each Chapter, that is, each child document, see [my previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300539/how-to-cross-reference-theorem-lemma-etc-as-for-example-theorem-1-in-lyx). but I am stuck again in cross referencing them aross Chapter 1, Chapter 2 and 3.

For example, in Chapter 2, I want to cross reference as according to "Proposition 1.1"...

Urgent help is much appreiciated as my thesis is due in less than a week (31st)
(I will delete this sentence after submission: ))

Comment: You are not providing any document. What do you mean by `child` document? Are the chapters located in in individual files? Normally, this should not pose any problem concerning the cross-referencing

Comment: It refers to a sub file in  LyX. You can insert a child document in a parent document by clicking: Insert-> File->child document. I did not know this either until I started using Classicthesis LyX version. The parent document is "classicthesis", the child documents are "Chapter 1" , "Titlepage" etc.

Comment: Well, it's a LyX 'feature' then -- I won't answer such questions

Comment: You have to keep the master document open, and open the children for editing  from it

Comment: I have not had any problems with cross-references across chapters. In your child documents, do you have the master document selected under Document > Settings > Document Class > "Select default master document" and then browse to select it?

Comment: I can confirm that it works even if I do not keep parent document open when inserting cross referencing. I just made a stupid mistake:  since the lemma is not cross referenced within the same child document, I forgot to insert a label. Please feel free to delete this question if you think it is stupid too. The only usefulness is to confirm that it automatically does the cross-child-document job as well.